# Probability of cryptocoin mining pool payout?

Tags: probability

I find probabilities incredibly interesting, but the methods used by cryptocoin mining pools have too many variables for me to make sense of. I'm a bit of a layman, so be easy on me. I'm hoping that somebody can simplify the probability of when and how much a particular payout plan will benefit a miner.

(I'm a Dogecoin miner so I'll speak specifically about doge. This should apply to Bitcoin and most other coins as well)

First, some mining definitions. Miners compute hashes (measured in thousands of hashes a second, KH/s) until the output meets certain criteria. There are 2 sets of criteria: Pool Difficulty and Network Difficulty. Network difficulty is more lax than pool difficulty. When a miner meets the criteria for the pool difficulty, it's called a Share. If the share also meets the harsher criteria for the network difficulty, a **Block** is said to be discovered. Discovering a block produces an award for the miner that produced the share that found it. If you mine solo, you get the entire reward. The difficulties fluctuate such that a block is discovered about once a minute. I'll be ignoring difficulty and just assuming that a block is found once a minute.

Pools work together so that if any one user finds a block, their reward is shared with all the users. When a pool miner finds a block, it ends a **Round**. A round usually lasts several blocks because other pools will find some of the blocks (Rounds are pool specific).

There are different methods for sharing this reward. More users usually means more blocks are found, but it also means the reward is divided amongst more people. Also miners that hash faster generally get a larger portion of the reward than miners that hash slower. Some pools give extra rewards to users who find blocks, but I'll ignore that here.

**Pay Per Last N Shares** (PPLNS) is almost exactly what it sounds like. When a round ends, a user will retrieve a portion of the reward dependent on how many of the last N shares the miner submitted (N is how many shares happened that round, since the last block this pool found). For example, let's say it's been 40,000,000 shares since the last round ended. If I submitted 10,000,000 of those shares and the reward for the block is 62,500, then I will be awarded 10,000,000/40,000,000 of those shares. 1/4 * 62,500 = 15,625 Doge.

If the entire Doge network is hashing at a rate of 50,000,000 KH/s and the pool is hashing at a rate of 15,000 KH/s, then the pool has (roughly) a chance of 15,000/50,000,000 of finding a block (0.03%) each block. Smaller hash rate means less chance to find a block. If I'm a bigger percentage of that smaller hash rate then I get a larger slice of the pie.

In short, I know that if I'm part of smaller pools, I'll get bigger rewards less often. If I'm part of larger pools, I get smaller rewards more often.

I suppose the real answer to this question is at what size pool can I maximize my total earnings over time, say in doge per day?

Comment: I have some follow up questions: if you double the pool size you participate in, is it fair to say that you double the probability of a reward, but the size of the reward will be half?

Comment: It's probably safer to say that if the pool's hashing rate doubled (but your own hash rate didn't) then your reward would be halved. But how the hashing rate of the pool compares to the hashing rate of the full network will also change.

Comment: But is a pool with double the hashing rate is also twice as likely to find a block per unit time?

Comment: If the pool brought new miners (say going from 15,000 KH/s to 30,000 KH/s) then the Network hash rate increased by the same amount (to 50,015,000) so the odds of discovering the next block are now ~0.0598% and not exactly twice as much. If they converted miners from other pools, it would be an exact doubling to 0.06% chance of finding a block. It's small, but I think non-negligible.

Comment: I see your point. But I was careful with my wording: I said block per unit time, and not block per round. My feeling is: if blocks are distributed uniformly, and you are mining along at a certain rate per unit time, then you should find blocks at a certain rate per unit time. If the network hash rate doubled but your pools stayed the same, then the network would go through rounds faster, but your pool should still expect to find the same number of blocks per day.

Comment: This is handled by the Network Difficulty. When a block is found in faster than 1 min, the difficulty is increased so that next time it only takes 1 minute. If a block takes longer than a minute, the difficulty is lowered. On average (I think) across the day 1 block will be found for each minute. The longer the timeline, the more this average should hold true.